# phalcon partial for multiple module

Tags: phalcon, partial, multi-module

```
$this->partial('partials/header');
```

This function for phalcon single module.

What can i do for this multiple-modules.
Can't work for this modules design.
I Went to use in multiple-modules design.

```
$this->partial('partials/header');
```

Please tell me

```
module1/
     views/
         about/      <- AboutController
         index/      <- IndexController
         index.phtml
module2/
     views/
         about/      <- AboutController
         index/      <- IndexController
         index.phtml
module3/
     views/
         about/      <- AboutController
         index/      <- IndexController
         index.phtml
         partials/   <- ()Store partials 
             header.phtml
             footer.phtml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go back few directories. For example if you want to include header.phtml from module3 in module1 (you may need to modify for your path):

```
$this->partial('../../module3/views/partials/header');
```

Answer (score 1):

Better create seperate view directory which will be used in every module. Add it to view compomnent and then you shouldn't need to go to this directory.